# How Does Commutativity of Double Series Relate to Counting Measure?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

So we have the theorem:

If $f_n:X\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $f(x)=\sum f_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$ then $\int_X f\, d\mu=\sum\int_X f_n\, d\mu$

and the author says if $\mu$ is the counting measure on a countable set, then the above theorem implies

If $a_{mn}\geq 0$ for all $m,n=1\ 2\ 3\ ...$ then $$\sum_m\sum_n a_{ij}=\sum_n\sum_m a_{ij}$$

Can somebody explain how this works? Thank you!

Comment: Integration with respect to the counting measure is just taking the infinite sum (assuming absolute convergence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{a_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$. If $\mu$ is the counting measure, then $\mu(\{a_m\})=1$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. So, writing $f_n(a_m):=a_{m,n}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m}\sum_{n}a_{m,n}&=\sum_{m}\sum_{n}f_n(a_m)=\sum_{m}\sum_{n}f_n(a_m)\mu(\{a_m\})=\sum_m f(a_m)\mu(\{a_m\})\\&=\int fd\mu=\sum_n\int f_nd\mu=\sum_{n}\sum_{m}a_{m,n}.
\end{align*}